# Add packages to yocto host sdk

Tags: sdk, ncurses, qemu, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to cross-compile a programme for a Yocto qemu using Yocto's sdk tools. After setting up the sdk and sourcing it, trying to cross-compile the programme fails thusly:

```
*** Unable to find the ncurses libraries or the
*** required header files.
*** 'make menuconfig' requires the ncurses libraries.
*** 
*** Install ncurses (ncurses-devel) and try again.
***
```

So I added `ncurses` to the `IMAGE_INSTALL` listing in the image's recipe, the same way I've installed other packages like dropbear, and confirmed that the `meta` layer that provides these packages was included in the `bblayers.conf` file. Then

```
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK += "nativesdk-ncurses nativesdk-ncurses-dev"
```

was also added to the image's recipe, to tell bitbake to give the host's sdk access to ncurses. I tried adding several variations on `nativesdk-ncurses-devel`, to more closely match what the error was asking for, but the image was unable to build with it. After that the image and sdk were re-built and re-sourced, but when attempting to cross compile the programme, it still asked for `Install ncurses (ncurses-devel) and try again`.

So my question is:

How is ncurses added properly to Yocto's host sdk environment? Is there a step I'm missing? Are the ncurses files needed not the same as those found in the `meta` layer?

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

-Patches

Comment: You can't do `TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK += "foo"`, you need to do `TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " foo"`.  I saw a mailing list post about this, but I can't find it again.  The gist is that it's defined with `?=` so `+=` overrides it completely.

Comment: This seems to be actually the correct answer as it seems that using the nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host.bb will not work if someone will make the sdk without that packagegroup (i.e. custom toolchains), this solution seems to be working when put inside the local.conf

Comment: To add to the above: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.0/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html#sdk-adding-individual-packages

Comment: I want to add pyyaml. Adding "nativesdk-python3-pyyaml" to the nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host.bb works for me but I want to have it in my local.conf or in my custom-layer that is tracked on my git repo. I couldn't archieve that so far. TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK:append = "python3-pyyaml" respectively TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK:append = "nativesdk-python3-pyyaml" showes me the following error: ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'packagegroup-cross-canadian-ls1046ardbpython3-pyyaml'

Comment: @SimonRechermann You are missing a space before your package name. Without it, the append creates an invalid value in the RPROVIDES list (which is space-separated).

Answer (score 2):

Please add needed package as *RDEPENDS_${PN}* in nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host.bb

https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/packagegroups/nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host.bb